# Jquery - Fazer loop numa funçao

Tags: jquery, upload, loop, multiple

Boa noite a todos. Estou aprendendo um pouco de Jquery e queria uma ajuda.
Tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btnEnviar').click(function(){
    var caminho = ("/uploads/");

    $("input[name='arquivo']").each(function() {


        $('#formUpload').ajaxForm({
            uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                $('progress').attr('value',percentComplete);
                $('#porcentagem').html(percentComplete+'%');
            },          
            success: function(data) {
                $('progress').attr('value','100');
                $('#porcentagem').html('100%');                
                if(data.sucesso == true){
                    $('#resposta').html('<img class="photo_uploaded" src="'+caminho+''+ data.msg +'" />');
                }
                else{
                    $('#resposta').html(data.msg);
                }                
            },
            error: function(){
                $('#resposta').html('Erro ao enviar requisição!!!');
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'upload3.php',
            resetForm: true
        });
    });
});
```

});

Estou tentando fazer um  loop da função para que cada imagem seja carregada de 1 em 1. Porém está garregando tudo junta. Alguem pode ajudar?

Desculpe qualquer erro de publicação.

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres dizer com "está carregando tudo junta"? Quantas imagens tens? vêm do ajax?

Comment: Bom, vamos lá. Coloquei apenas 2 input type="file" para testar.

As barra de progress estão encehndo juntas, o que indica que está executando apenas uma vez o upload e não pode, afinal são 2 input. Então tem que ser a seguinte logica:

Para cada input, execute a função de upload.